# Remove duplicate rel attributes in HTML using c#

Tags: c#, html

I have an HTML document with a number of links. Some of these links contain two identical rel attributes, and I would like to iterate over all of the a-tags, check if there are more than one rel attribute and remove one if there is, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Example:

```
<a rel="nofollow" rel="nofollow" href="blah"> link<a>
```

Should be:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="blah"> link<a>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If are you attributes are identical, this is a possible solution using nuget [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/)

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var html = 
        @"
        <div>
            <a rel='nofollow' rel='nofollow' href='lah'> link1</a>
            <a rel='qwerty' rel='qwerty' href='lah'> link2</a>
            <a rel='asdf' rel='asdf' href='lah'> link3</a>
        </div>";

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

        var htmlNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a");

        foreach (var node in htmlNodes)
        {
            var attr = node.Attributes["rel"];
            while(node.Attributes.Contains("rel")) node.Attributes.Remove("rel");

            node.Attributes.Add("rel", attr.Value);
        }
        using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        htmlDoc.Save(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
        var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        System.Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @krlosmederos.
Actually there might be some of the attributes that contain different values. How would I go about ensuring I only target the ones that contain the value 'nofollow'?
Thanks again!

Comment: With node.Attributes["rel"].Value get the attributes's value and then compare